# Rails subtracting one variable from another

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, function, math

I have the following code:

```
<script>


        var target = <%= @main.sum(&:target) %>;
        var forecast = <%= @main.sum(&:forecast) %>;
        var achieved = <%= @main.sum(&:achieved) %>;

    var pieData = [
            {
                value: target,
                color:"#ed1c24"
            },
            {
                value : achieved,
                color : "#000"
            }


        ];

        var opt = {
            scaleFontFamily : "'Trebuchet'",
            segmentStrokeColor : "#fff",

        }
```

and I need to see how much of the target has been achieved on a pie chart. The code works, I just need a way to subtract the `achieved` figure from the `target` figure

Comment: what's wrong with `var difference = target - achieved`?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an important piece of your code, you could insert this into your model. The code would read:

```
model.rb

def difference
  self.sum(&:target) - self.sum(&:acheived)
end

js:

var difference = @main.difference;
```

While you could put this in the javascript, since this is within a view it might be good to keep the calculation in your model so you can have a degree of visibility as to what is going on within your application logic, within one file.